# Only Single Item Displayed from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

here is my code snippet for all Messages in my database from android..

```
public List<Message> getAllRow()
{
    List<Message> list=new LinkedList<Message>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String RAW_QUERY="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(RAW_QUERY, null);
    Message message=null;

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            message=new Message();
            message.setId(cursor.getString(0));
            message.setFaculty(cursor.getString(1));
            message.setMessage(cursor.getString(2));
            list.add(message);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d("GET ALL ROW ",message.toString());
    return list;

}
```

but when i execute the command in MainActivity like

```
List<Message> list =db.getAllRow();
```

or

```
db.getAllRow();
```

Only last item which I have inserted in table is being displayed in Logcat what about other rows.?/

Comment: Just as a tip: instead of a do/while loop + an if statement just do a while loop -   while(cursor.moveToNext()) {  } it's effectively the same code just much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: I dont get it what you are trying to say.@dymmeh

Comment: Others are in the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one message in the logcat because the code calls `Log.d` only once.

To display all items, you have to log each item inside the loop:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(RAW_QUERY, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setId(cursor.getString(0));
    message.setFaculty(cursor.getString(1));
    message.setMessage(cursor.getString(2));
    list.add(message);
    Log.d("get one row ", message.toString());
}
return list;
```

Comment: thanks I finally had a solution. It not my code fault I misplaced Log.d